# Array Size (Length) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, size

How can I determine size of an array (length / number of items) in C#?

Comment: @Marcelo: ...but it still can't answer really simple questions like "Where are my glasses". ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "size"? The number of elements or size in bytes?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet I upvoted because I had the same problem of finding Length didn't work for multi-dimensional arrays and as a result of this question discovering Rank and GetLength(index).

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet I believe the fact that it has 145,000 views is a testament to its relevance. Upvoted.

Answer (score 174):

If it's a one-dimensional array `a`,

```
a.Length
```

will give the number of elements of `a`.

If `b` is a rectangular multi-dimensional array (for example, `int[,] b = new int[3, 5];`)

```
b.Rank
```

will give the number of dimensions (2) and

```
b.GetLength(dimensionIndex)
```

will get the length of any given dimension (0-based indexing for the dimensions - so `b.GetLength(0)` is 3 and `b.GetLength(1)` is 5).

See [System.Array documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

As @Lucero points out in the comments, there is a concept of a "jagged array", which is really nothing more than a single-dimensional array of (typically single-dimensional) arrays.

For example, one could have the following:

```
int[][] c = new int[3][];
c[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
c[1] = new int[] {3, 14};
c[2] = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13};
```

Note that the 3 members of `c` all have different lengths.
In this case, as before `c.Length` will indicate the number of elements of `c`, (3) and `c[0].Length`, `c[1].Length`, and `c[2].Length` will be 3, 2, and 7, respectively.

Comment: For completeness you could also have listed the way jagged arrays work (e.g. `int[][]`) ;-)

Comment: I considered it, @Lucerno, but figured it a different problem - figuring out the size of things _inside_ an array - a jagged array's really just a single-dimensioned array that happens to contain singled-dimensioned arrays, as I'm  sure you know.

Comment: of course I know that you're right and that's why I added the comment with a smiley instead of writing an answer myself. However, the distinction between `[,]` and `[][]` doesn't seem to be clear for all .NET newbies, so it may still be worth noting that `[][]` is not a multidimensional array in your answers sense.

Comment: Good answer. But, you might want to change `b.GetLength[0] is 3 and b.GetLength[1] is 5` should be `b.GetLength(0) and b.GetLength(1)`.

Answer (score 32):

You can look at the [documentation for Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_members.aspx) to find out the answer to this question.

In this particular case you probably need [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx):

```
int sizeOfArray = array.Length;
```

But since this is such a basic question and you no doubt have many more like this, rather than just telling you the answer I'd rather tell you how to find the answer yourself.

**Visual Studio Intellisense**

When you type the name of a variable and press the `.` key it shows you a list of all the methods, properties, events, etc. available on that object. When you highlight a member it gives you a brief description of what it does.

[image]

**Press F1**

If you find a method or property that might do what you want but you're not sure, you can move the cursor over it and press F1 to get help. Here you get a much more detailed description plus links to related information.

**Search**

The search terms [`size of array in C#`](http://www.google.com/search?q=size+of+array+in+c%23) gives many links that tells you the answer to your question and much more. One of the most important skills a programmer must learn is how to find information. It is often faster to find the answer yourself, especially if the same question has been asked before.

**Use a tutorial**

If you are just beginning to learn C# you will find it easier to follow a tutorial. I can recommend the [C# tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN. If you want a book, I'd recommend [Essential C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533925).

**Stack Overflow**

If you're not able to find the answer on your own, please feel free to post the question on Stack Overflow. But we appreciate it if you show that you have taken the effort to find the answer yourself first.

Comment: Good job, Mark, but may be an overkill!

Comment: @Nayan: Thanks! While it's great that the OP got his answer fast from other posters, I feel it's more important to teach beginners how to find information rather than teaching them answers to specific questions. I hope the OP finds this answer useful and that it saves them having to ask hundreds of questions that they could have found the answers to themselves.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to take this approach - "give a man a fish..." etc.

Comment: If I ever have to do the same, I'll just redirect the OPs to your answer here =) And yes, I completely agree with you!

Comment: This is good but I feel it should be linked to automatically somehow.  Can't they start a "answers worth viewing" page?  One thing that I would add though is that one should check stack overflow itself before posting the question.  Often times I just start posting the question and then see the related questions that popup.  I am not sure if the answer exists elsewhere on the internet if it doesn't belong here too.

Comment: What a waste of your time! Before you lecture the OP on searching for answers i think it is safe to say that none of the answers here address the actual question. The OP asked how to get the SIZE of the array NOT the length. My search for this same question  brought me here. I would like to know how to determine the SIZE of the array not how many items are in the array. For example new string[5]{"foo"} = an array with a SIZE of 5 and has a LENGTH of 1.. get it? if I have an array passed into a method how do I know if it will hold another value or not? Compare SIZE and LENGTH

Answer (score 20):

for 1 dimensional array

```
int[] listItems = new int[] {2,4,8};
int length = listItems.Length;
```

for multidimensional array

```
int length = listItems.Rank;
```

To get the size of 1 dimension

```
int length =  listItems.GetLength(0);
```

Comment: The `Rank` property doesn't return the number of items, it returns the number of dimensions.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for the properties supported by 1 dimensional arrays? (i.e., `Length`, `Rank`, `GetLength`)

Answer (score 11):

`yourArray.Length` :)

Answer (score 8):

With the `Length` property.

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
int n = foo.Length; // n == 10
```

Answer (score 5):

For a single dimension array, you use the `Length` property:

```
int size = theArray.Length;
```

For multiple dimension arrays the `Length` property returns the total number of items in the array. You can use the `GetLength` method to get the size of one of the dimensions:

```
int size0 = theArray.GetLength(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

In most of the general cases 'Length' and 'Count' are used.

Array:

```
int[] myArray = new int[size];
int noOfElements = myArray.Length;
```

Typed List Array:

```
List <int> myArray = new List<int>();
int noOfElements = myArray.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

it goes like this:
1D:

```
 type[] name=new type[size]  //or =new type[]{.....elements...}
```

2D:

```
 type[][]name=new type[size][] //second brackets are emtpy
```

then as you use this array :

```
 name[i]=new type[size_of_sec.Dim]
```

or You can declare something like a  matrix

```
type[ , ] name=new type [size1,size2]
```

Answer (score 1):

What has been missed so far is what I suddenly was irritated about:

How do I know the amount of items inside the array? Is `.Length` equal `.Count` of a List?

The answer is: the amount of items of type X which have been put into an array of type X created with `new X[number]` **you have to carry yourself**!

Eg. using a counter: `int countItemsInArray = 0` and `countItemsInArray++` for every assignment to your array.

(The array just created with `new X[number]` has all space for `number` items (references) of type X already allocated, you can assign to any place inside as your first assignment, for example (if `number` = 100 and the variable name = `a`) `a[50] = new X();`.

I don't know whether C# specifies the initial value of each place inside an array upon creation, if it doesn't or the initial value you cannot compare to (because it might be a value you yourself have put into the array), you would have to track which places inside the array you already assigned to too if you don't assign sequentially starting from `0` (in which case all places smaller than `countItemsInArray` would be assigned to).)

In your question *size of an array (length / number of items)* depending on whether */* is meant to stand for "alternative" or "divide by" the latter still has to be covered (the "number of items" I just gave as "amount of items" and others gave `.Length` which corresponds to the value of `number` in my code above):

C# has a `sizeof` operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof). It's safe to use for built-in types (such as int) (and only operates on types (not variables)). Thus the size of an array `b` of type `int` in bytes would be `b.Length * sizeof(int)`.

(Due to all space of an array already being allocated on creation, like mentioned above, and `sizeof` only working on types, no code like `sizeof(variable)/sizeof(type)` would work or yield the amount of items without tracking.)